# Devise, flash message when require_no_authentication + redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, rubygems, devise, ruby-on-rails-3

Could you tell me whats the best practice to include flash messages f.e. *"You must be logged out to view the requested site"*,

when the **require_no_authentication-filter** is set and the user accesses a site, which becomes filtered. The flash message should appear in every controller where i call the before filter, not only in the device controllers (so inheritance isn't enough)...

Per default there are no flash-messages, which is absurd, from my point of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour was changed from the device maintainers. You are now able to do that the same way the other hooks become called.